# Can I import a single row (indexed) from a csv file into a zsh array?

Tags: zsh, csv, array

I want to parse a csv file in zsh row by row and store it in an array (without the commas). Is it possible to import a single row into an array in zsh, then afterwards grab the next row?

The issue is I am using a large csv file and cannot import it all quickly. I tried using the code below:

```
arr_csv=() 
while IFS= read -r line 
do
    arr_csv+=("$line")
done < import.csv
```

but since the file is large, I want to read and store a single line (or access a single line).

I understand I could modify the code such that

```
arr_csv=() 
while IFS= read -r line 
do
    arr_csv=("$line")
    # some modifications
done < import.csv
```

but if I wanted to loop over the file it would be easier if I could use an index corresponding to the row from the csv file. Also, this method does not remove the commas separating the rows.

Comment: What do you want to do with the array once you've read it in? There may be better tools (`csvkit`, `miller`, `awk`, `python`, `perl`, etc.)

Comment: Related: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)  As roaima says, depending on what you want to do with the data, using a dedicated CSV parser may be better than parsing it with the shell. This would also make it easier to handle fields with embedded commas, newlines and quotes.

Comment: @roaima  I am purposefully using zsh as a side project for myself. I am purposefully using a suboptimal language for this project.

Comment: @Kusalananda also, all of the csv data are numbers, so I wanted a formatted array where the array can be indexed and not just a string

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that rather calls for using a proper programming language with CSV support such as `perl` / `python`... here rather than a shell.

But, if you have to use `zsh` and don't mind the newline and carriage return from individual cells being removed, you could use csvkit's `csvformat` to reformat the csv into something that `zsh`'s `read` can deal with more easily:

```
< file.csv csvformat -SU3 -P'\' |
  while IFS=, read -A array; do
    typeset array # or anything with $array
  done
```

For instance, on an input like:

```
"foo bar ", "x,y", "blah""blah","new
line"
1,,2,"\\"
```

Which includes samples of typical potential pitfalls associated with csvs, that gives:

```
array=( 'foo bar ' x,y 'blah"blah' newline )
array=( 1 '' 2 '\\' )
```

Note the absence of `-r` so `read` does recognise `\` as an escape character. Unfortunately, while `csvformat` escapes `<newline>` with `\<newline>`, for `read`, that's interpreted as a line continuation rather than an escaped newline.

If you know of two characters that never occur in the input, you could use those as field delimiter and record delimiter respectively. For instance, could be the ASCII *Record Separator* and *Unit Separator* control characters which would be seem fitting here.

```
us=$'\x1f' rs=$'\x1e'
< file.csv csvformat -SU3 -D$us -M$rs -Q$rs |
  while IFS=$us read -rd$rs -A array; do
    something with $array
  done
```

Which this time, on the same input gives:

```
array=( 'foo bar ' x,y 'blah"blah' $'new\nline' )
array=( 1 '' 2 '\\' )
```